# Unity3D - How to create flat map render based on endless noise data

Tags: unity, procedural-generation, maps, unityscript, heightmap

**The Project**

I'm working actually on a Endless Map Generator (with chunks, height-map noise, threading system, etc..)
This is actually what "dev data display" look like:

[image]

**The Goal**

Now I want to create another flat rendering (for example the mini-map) with simple Sprite (I have some Photoshop Brush, or other images).

Example (from internet):
[image]

**Questions**

This post isn't really about seed data recovery but more **How do I transform that data into nice map ?**

- Do I have to keep doing 3D or replace by a 2D Canvas ?
- Do Texture is good for the job ? Or it will be easier to instantiate multiple sprite ? (Or maybe a shader ?)
- I have a special question for Shapes (like actually water). I didn't found anything who can help me to transform a list of dots (like all coords next to the ground) into a smooth shape who can be used on shader or other display.

A already try to use plane (instead of generated mesh) and apply the texture with a Level Of Detail system to smooth the closest part of the map. But it's still very ulgy.
[image]